# Reduction of silicon dioxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

Silicon dioxide, in the form of quartz, is in abundance around my local area and I would be interested in creating silicon as a separate element.
My problem is that I don't know what to react silicon dioxide with to reduce it to silicon. I have read that it can be reduced with carbon but I couldn't find any information about the temperatures this takes place at. I am also aware that a thermic reaction can take place between aluminium and silicon when mixed with sulfur but I don't have any aluminium powder.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon#Metallurgical_grade

Comment: @hex can you build an answer around that reference?  The given answer is rejected as not an answer, and for my part I am not convinced it would work.

Comment: @OscarLanzi When I post it a year ago the link was different as it is today. However if you read the wikipedia page and the references you'll find what you want. I have no time to read for others and as I am not a specialist of the question ... :-)